# Pandas, If value isin column then make change to another column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to do:  IF a column contains values , then apply a change to joinkey column, IF a column contains different values, then apply a different change to joinkey column, etc.

IF  `df.loc[df['product'].isin('value1','value2')` THEN `df['joinkey'] = df['joinkey'] + variable1`

then repeat

IF  `df.loc[df['product'].isin('value3','value4')` THEN `df['joinkey'] = df['joinkey'] + variable2`

Hopefully this makes sense, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: why not try to use np.where ? this should do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try and use `np.where()` for the column, maybe it will requiere more than one line of code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['joinkey'] = np.where(df['product'].isin(['value1','value2']),df['joinkey']+variable1,df['joinkey'])
df['joinkey'] = np.where(df['product'].isin(['value3','value4']),df['joinkey']+variable2,df['joinkey'])
```

I've setted the `false` condition to be equal to the original value of `joinkey` but of course you can change that to fit your needs best.

Comment: Why do you mention the joinkey again after the last comma?

Comment: Simply because of setting the false condition to the original value of `joinkey` but providing the flexibility for the user to change it to whatever he/she wants. I assume this, since it is not given. Also from numpy's documentation, either both or none of x and y should be given, therefore I can't leave it blank.